# Microphone filter/ foam screen - to reduce fan noise

Tags: audio, homerecording, noise

I live in India, a hot tropical country. Ceiling fans are indispensable parts of our lives. And naturally, the noise from it screws up my recordings (audio and video - done on my phone).

What can I do (other than stopping the fan, that is) o reduce, if not eliminate, the noise? 
Condenser microphone with (Pop filter, foam screen etc.) or anything else?

Comment: Exactly what are you recording? Voice, guitar, drums?

Comment: digital piano. i am novice. but realised that recording, with video is a good feedback system.

Comment: There may be a way to d.i. the piano into the recording machine, thus cutting out use of mic.

Comment: Like a simple earphone jack? I record on my phone. Actually, that may work! Why didn't I think of that??!!

Answer (score 1):

A pop filter or foam screen will not stop fan noise. You really only have two effective options:

- stop the fan. This is the simplest and most common route. Many recording studios put effort into ensuring air conditioning machinery is segregated from audio booths.
- use a directional microphone pointed at the singer/instrument to ensure it only picks up sound from that direction.

Comment: Thank you. will read up directional microphone. will there be any difference between condenser and dynamic.